# Can nginx reverse proxy isolate cache per endpoint?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm using nginx reverse proxy to cache content from two endpoints, one of which is very reliable; the other has frequent timeouts.

I've found that those timeouts can sometimes use up all available connections or cause other issues, degrading performance for the server as a whole and leading to increased latency for the reliable endpoint as well.

I've tweaked some settings (worker_rlimit_nofile, worker_connections), but what I'd really like to do is isolate the caching and connections for the two endpoints as much as possible: give each a share of the available cache, and a share of the available connections, and operate as if they're hitting two separate servers, to reduce the chances that issues with one endpoint affect the performance of the other.

If I were to create two location blocks, one for each endpoint, can I designate each block's share of the cache (e.g. number of files, or total size) and share of available connections?

Or is there a better way of achieving this goal of isolation to ensure reliable performance for the good endpoint, even if the bad endpoint is experiencing lots of timeouts?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the `proxy_cache_*` directives can be specific to location blocks and will allow you to do just that.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache

It may also help others answer if an example config is provided that reflects what you're currently doing.